# How to make this function async?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, service

How do I turn the below function in a async function?

```
  getHandledSheet(): void {
    this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().subscribe({next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {this.timesheetsHandled = response.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED') }})
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Matthieu's answer but fixing the syntax errors:

```js
const timesheetObservable = this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets();
const timesheets = await firstValueFrom(timesheetObservable);
this.timesheetsHandled = timesheets.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED');
```

Comment: Thanks but it also doesn't compile.

Comment: what's the error this time?

Comment: It cannot read response nor sheet: 
Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'? && Parameter 'sheet' implicitly has an 'any' type;;;; Also next is not used

Comment: ah yes, I've updated my code and maybe that will help you

Comment: I only had the error left: Parameter 'sheet' implicitly has an 'any' type, I switch the 'any' with TimeSheet[], which made it compile.  But unfortunatly it doesnt make it async function. I need it that my program waits untill this function is executed before to continue.

Comment: Yes it's fine to switch `any` to `TimeSheet[]`. Ok you need `await` if you want it to run sequentially (waiting for it). I've updated my code. If this answers your question, can you mark my code as the answer please :)

Comment: It also needs async and Promise<void>, than it compiles, but it doesn't run async.

Comment: use `await` when you call `getHandledSheet` if you want to wait for that function to run. Alternatively use `void` if you want it to run in parallel. Though I suspect you want `await getHandledSheet(.....)`

Answer (score 1):

`firstValueFrom` will return a promise with the first value sent by the `Observable`

```
firstValueFrom(this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets()).then({next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {this.timesheetsHandled = response.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED') }})
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: TimeSheet[]) => TimeSheet[] | PromiseLike<TimeSheet[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'next' does not exist in type '(value: TimeSheet[]) => TimeSheet[] | PromiseLike<TimeSheet[]>